# SPARQL query with large number of values inside 'values' block

Tags: sparql, rdf, subgraph

I have a list of nodes and I want to retrieve the triples containing all the relations between those nodes.

This is what I've done so far:

```
PREFIX myPrefix:  <http://example.org/myPrefix/>
SELECT ?a ?relation ?b
WHERE{
values ?a { myPrefix:id_00083184 myPrefix:id_00083187
            myPrefix:id_00083189 myPrefix:id_00083182
            myPrefix:id_09463313 myPrefix:id_00000790
            myPrefix:id_00073965 myPrefix:id_00073966
            myPrefix:id_00016990 myPrefix:id_08380001
            myPrefix:id_00019131 myPrefix:id_03739215
            myPrefix:id_00019129 myPrefix:id_00034482
            myPrefix:id_00098617                     

            }

values ?b { myPrefix:id_00083184 myPrefix:id_00083187
            myPrefix:id_00083189 myPrefix:id_00083182
            myPrefix:id_09463313 myPrefix:id_00000790
            myPrefix:id_00073965 myPrefix:id_00073966
            myPrefix:id_00016990 myPrefix:id_08380001
            myPrefix:id_00019131 myPrefix:id_03739215
            myPrefix:id_00019129 myPrefix:id_00034482
            myPrefix:id_00098617                     
             }
    ?a ?relation ?b .
}
```

With this I get what I want, that is, all the relations between the nodes on my (external) list; using `values` and repeating the nodes for `?a` and `?b`. But the problem is, my nodes list can be very large; sometimes it can have up to 1000 nodes and that's just a small case; and that query takes too long to execute.

Is there a better way to do what I need? This is the only approach I've found but I'm not very fluent in SPARQL so, any way of doing it correctly?

PS: I get the nodes list externally from a query from another database and using Java I construct the query appending every node on the list.

This all sounds very caveman-ish for me but as I said, I'm starting to use SPARQL.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did think that you can improve the performance of the query as it's rather a very simple query. If you have `n` nodes the complexity of a naive solution is obviously `O(n²)`

Comment: How do you think I can improve the performance of my query? I mean, that's sort of my question @AKSW

Comment: Ehm sorry, I meant "I don't think so". Of course, if the relation is symmetric, you could try to avoid checking both `a r b` and `b r a`, but that would be your task during construction of the query indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing now is probably the most general way to do this.

Individual APIs, e.g., Jena, may support other ways to specify a set of initial bindings that are functionally equivalent to a values block, but could let the actual query be much shorter.  For example, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17776485/1281433) to [Saving and reusing the result of a SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17766541/1281433).  The answer to [Add text search where clause to SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25164499/1281433) also has an example of initial bindings in Jena.